# How to validate Rails model based on a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `User` model, and need to validate phone number attribute based on the controller param.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :phone_number
end
```

This validation should validate `phone_number` in the `Create` action. 
Let's say the param I should check is

```
 params[:phone_number]
```

Comment: If you want to validate phone_number only for `create` action, you can add `before_create` callback

Comment: Yes, that is true.. but this validation should happen based on the param i get to my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many ways to complete this task,

1. I used Inheritance - Created a sub class from the User class
2. Call a method in the model from the controller to set the attribute and bind that attribute with the validation
3. Use the context option

I guess the context option is the most reliable solution for this issue i faced. So here when i set the context as :interface the model validation will trigger only based on that value

**Model - User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :phone_number, on: :interface
end
```

**Controller - users_controller.rb**

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@save_result = false
if params[:invitation_token] == nil
  save_result = @user.save(context: :interface)
else
  save_result = @user.save
end
```

If you use multiple options in ON:

```
  validates  :terms_and_conditions, acceptance: {accept: true}, on: [:create, :interface], unless: :child
  validates  :privacy_policy, acceptance: {accept: true}, on: [:create, :interface], unless: :child
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use before_save validation, in User model you can write

```
before_save :validate_phone_number
private
def validate_phome_number
   self.phone_number = /some regex/
end
```

In self.phone_number you will get controller params by default

Answer (score 1):

```
validate :custom_validation, :on => :create

private
def custom_validation
   //whatever you want to check
end
```